# How to access textarea's value through javascript in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textarea

I have a textarea and i am using a plugin for that textarea. In that plugin there is a function getCode() which will return the value of the textarea. That function will be called like - `textarea_id.getCode();`

I am using ASP.NET in which i have declared the textarea (runat=server), and the textarea'a id i can get but when i am writing the following code it is not calling the method.

```
'<%= txtName.ClientID %>'.getCode();
```

But if i am writing then it is working fine.

```
ctrl001_txtxName.getCode();
```

Because the first one is a string and the second one i guess is an object. If so then how to overcome this problem. Can anyone please help?

### Code Block

```
Plugin = function(obj)
{
    var self = document.createElement('iframe');
    self.textarea = obj;
    self.textarea.disabled = true;
    self.textarea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    self.style.height = self.textarea.clientHeight + 'px';
    self.style.width = self.textarea.clientWidth + 'px';
    self.textarea.style.overflow = 'auto';
    self.style.border = '1px solid gray';
    self.frameBorder = 0; // remove IE internal iframe border
    self.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    self.style.position = 'absolute';
    self.options = self.textarea.className;

    self.initialize = function()
    {
        self.editor = self.contentWindow.CodePress;
        self.editor.body = self.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        self.editor.setCode(self.textarea.value);
        self.setOptions();
        self.editor.syntaxHighlight('init');
        self.textarea.style.display = 'none';
        self.style.position = 'static';
        self.style.visibility = 'visible';
        self.style.display = 'inline';
    }

    self.getCode = function()
    {
        return self.textarea.disabled ? self.editor.getCode() : self.textarea.value;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('<%= txtName.ClientID %>').getCode();
```

Comment: No it's not working. Only ctrl001_txtxName.getCode(); is working fine. Even "ctrl001_txtxName".getCode(); is also not working. Can we not change a string to an object?

Comment: or try: `<%= txtName.ClientID %>.getCode();` (notice no single quotes)

Comment: Thanks "<%= txtName.ClientID %>.getCode();" is working fine but can you tell me what is the exact difference?

Comment: `'<%= txtName.ClientID %>'` will produce a string, `<%= txtName.ClientID %>` will product an object. which is why i was surprised my original answer did not work.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted. :)